# longtblr captions

Tags: captions, tabularray

I like to have different caption text on the first and other page spanned by long table `longtblr`. If possible a text which is intended to LoT and inserted `longtblr` by `entry={short caption text>}`). How to achieve this?

For example, in the following MWE I like to have in the second caption the text *Short version of the caption (Continued)*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Longtable captions which span three lines and not appear in LoT. How to prevent that this text will not be shown on the next pages of this table but rather some shorter text, preferable content of \texttt{entry} option?},
    entry = {Short version of the caption},
    label = {longtable},
                ]{rowhead=1,
                  hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {X[0.2,j] X[0.3,j] X[0.53,j]},
                  colsep=4pt,
                   row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
                  }
%   column headers
Left column &   Midle column    &   Long Column         \\
%   table body
\lipsum[66]
    &   \lipsum[11]      
        &   \lipsum[1]  \\
\lipsum[66]
    &   \lipsum[11]
        &   \lipsum[1]  \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a Template that uses the `entry` parameter in the continuation caption (`capcont`), and a theme to specify its use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\listoftables 

\DefTblrTemplate {caption-text}{short}{\InsertTblrText{entry}}

\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{short}{%
  \par\centering
  \UseTblrTemplate {caption-tag}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate {caption-sep}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate {caption-text}{short}
  \UseTblrTemplate {conthead-text}{default}
  \par
}
\NewTblrTheme{shortcaption}{%
    \SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{short}%
}

\begin{longtblr}[theme = shortcaption,
  caption = {Longtable captions which span two lines and not appear in LoT. How to prevent that not be shown on the next pages of this table?},
    entry = {Short version of the caption},
    label = {longtable},
                ]{rowhead=1,
                  hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {X[0.2,j] X[0.3,j] X[0.53,j]},
                  colsep=4pt,
                   row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
                  }
%   column headers
Left column &   Midle column    &   Long Column         \\
%   table body
\lipsum[66]
    &   \lipsum[11]      
        &   \lipsum[1]  \\
\lipsum[66]
    &   \lipsum[11]
        &   \lipsum[1]  \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]