# tabularray: How to have different "continued captions"?

Tags: tabularray

- I am looking for a way to have a **different caption text for continued captions**.
- I assume that is related to `middlehead` and or `lasthead` but I did not understand how to use it.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
% "margin = 54mm" is used to control the page break for the MWE.
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 54mm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {First Caption},
  % mid-caption = {Other Captions}, % <-- Pseudo Code :)
  % last-caption = {Other Captions}, % <-- Pseudo Code :)
  entry = {LoT Caption},
  label = {tab:label};
]{
  colspec = {t{0.20\linewidth}t{0.20\linewidth}t{0.20\linewidth}},
  rowhead = 1,
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
}
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\toprule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Related but for `longtable`: [Table captions continued](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115195)
- Related: [longtblr captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624625)

Comment: In this particular case, you would have to redefine `lasthead` not `middlehead`.

Comment: @marv Thanks for the comment, I will update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not understand why you want to use different captions in different pages of a long table. It looks a little weird to me. But anyway it is doable: just past two captions to the `caption` key and retrieve them later with some helper commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,top=35mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\FirstOfTwo{m}{
  \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \use_i:nn { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\SecondOfTwo{m}{
  \exp_last_unbraced:Ne \use_ii:nn { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{first}{\FirstOfTwo{\InsertTblrText{caption}}}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{second}{\SecondOfTwo{\InsertTblrText{caption}}}

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead}{default}{
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{first}
  \par
}
\DefTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{default}{
  \centering
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{second}
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {First Caption}{Second Caption},
  entry = {LoT Caption},
  label = {tab:label};
]{
  colspec = {t{0.2\linewidth}t{0.2\linewidth}t{0.2\linewidth}},
  rowhead = 1,
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
}
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\toprule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The reason is that the caption is very long.

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach would be to define a command to hardcode the text for the `middlehead` and `lasthead`. With the command `\SetMidLastCaption`, you can place any text you like in the "continued captions".

Obviously, it would be much better to define a new key, e.g. `mid-caption` as you suggested. However, I am not that familiar with `expl3`, maybe someone else can help.

Found a solution, see edit below.

```
\documentclass{article}
% "margin = 54mm" is used to control the page break for the MWE.
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 54mm, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \SetMidLastCaption }{ m }{
    \DefTblrTemplate{ middlehead, lasthead }{ default }
    {
      \centering
      #1
      \par
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Use the following command to reset the captions to normal behaviour
%\SetTblrTemplate{middlehead,lasthead}{normal}

\begin{document}
    
    \SetMidLastCaption{Other Captions}

    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {First Caption},
        % mid-caption = {Other Captions}, % <-- Pseudo Code :)
        entry = {LoT Caption},
        label = {tab:label};
        ]{
            colspec = {t{0.20\linewidth}t{0.20\linewidth}t{0.20\linewidth}},
            rowhead = 1,
            row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        }
        \toprule
        A & B & C \\
        \toprule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\\midrule
        a & b & c\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: first caption]
[image: second caption]

**Edit:** Defintion of new key `midlast-caption`

The following code defines the key `midlast-caption` as an outer key (used in the optional argument) for `tblr`. The assignment should be local, meaning if you do not provide the key the captions should use the `normal` template. If you use `midlast-caption = {Other Captions}` in the optional argument, the result will be the same as in my first example.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_gput_left:Nn \g__tblr_table_known_keys_clist { midlast-caption }
\keys_define:nn { tblr-outer } { midlast-caption .code:n = \__tblr_set_midlast_caption:n { #1 } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tblr_set_midlast_caption:n #1 {
    \DefTblrTemplate{ middlehead, lasthead }{ default }
    {
        \centering
        #1
        \par
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

**Disclaimer** I am a complete novice to `expl3`. Therefore this code might be very bad, use it with caution. I am thankfull for everyone who improves this code.

Comment: Thanks and +1! Let's see if there are more answers.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner found a way to define this as a new key. See the edit.

Comment: I appreciate the effort! Greetings to a fellow German mechatronics engineer.